# Where is the rest of my MacBook’s hard disk space?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, memory-management

I have a MacBook Pro with a 250GB hard drive. Right now I'm left with only 4GB free memory.

I've selected the root folder in Finder (my computer name) and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to get the size of all items together. I got 184GB.

My questions:

1. Where did the remaining 70GB disappear to and how can I locate it?
2. When I'm left with 1.2GB I get a startup disk is full, what does Mac need 1GB for in order to run?

Answer (score 3):

> I’ve selected the root folder in Finder (my computer name) and hit
>   <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and
>   <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to get the size of all
>   items together I got 184GB.
>
> My question is where did the remaining 70GB disappear to and how can I
>   locate it.

The 184GB is how much space all of your system and applications take up. The remaining 70GB is your free space.

Instead of checking space the way describe—by selecting folders—you can just select your hard drive and do <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show you the disk info. It should show three values:

- **Capacity:** The capacity/size of the hard drive volume in question which should be about 250GB.
- **Available:** The amount of available space remaining on that hard drive volume which should be 70GB.
- **Used** The amount of space used on that hard drive volume which should be 184GB.

Another way of checking your system’s disk usage is to open up a “Terminal” window and use [`df`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/df.1.html) (display free disk space) with the `-h` for human readable output:

```
df -h
```

The output would be something like this; numbers reflect my Mac OS X setup:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   465Gi   35Gi  430Gi     8%   9146040 112740702    8%   /
devfs          192Ki  192Ki    0Bi   100%       664         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /home
```

Look at the numbers, `/dev/disk0s2` and you can see similar options to the “Finder” “Get Info…” data in the top line:

- **Size:** The capacity/size of the hard drive volume in question which should be about 250GB.
- **Used** The amount of space used on that hard drive volume.
- **Avail:** The amount of available space remaining on that hard drive volume.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, reading your answer and going back to the question, figured I didn't write the most important fact I have 4 GB of Free memory that is why I'm asking where did the 70 GB gone...sorry for that, I've edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

`About This Mac -> More Info -> Storage` will show you. Probably behind a partition. Run `diskutil list` to find out.